# Flagging rows where a value changed from previous row

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a query that is tracking production.  Whenever a unit is produced I capture the timestamp, part number, delta time, and what the cycle time should have been, as well as others that aren’t important to list here.  In a SSRS report I count the rows and group them by hour and run efficiency calculations each hour based on the cycle times divided by the deltas.  What I need is to add a column in my select statement that will flag whenever a part number changes so I can identify when a changeover has occurred by referencing it in my report.

Example: Select part number of row – part number of previous row as changeover

Every row would have a value that would always be 0 unless a changeover occurred then it would be a different value for that one row.  I could have my report do its thing on any value <> 0.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012 there is a `LAG()` function that you could use, but there is a longer workaround for older versions of SQL Server. Trust me when I say that there are many SO questions in which this is answered (as I've had to look!).

Comment: can you show your existing report.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm 2 reputation points away from being able to post a picture.  It's a count by hour report that turns red, yellow, or green based on efficiency percentage.  I've added a blue whenever I count 2 distinct part numbers in a single hour, but I miss changeovers when a unit is built in one hour and the first unit, after changeover, is built in the next hour. I need to flag the change in my select statement so I can reference the flag in my report to turn the hour with a flag blue.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by SQLHound, if you're using SQL Server 2012 or another database that supports the LAG function then you can use this in your SQL query.

A SQL Server example:

```
SELECT
  partnumber,
  somevalue,
  CASE
    WHEN LAG(partnumber, 1) OVER (ORDER BY partnumber) <> partnumber THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS PartNumberChangeOver
FROM ntest;
```

[see it on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72a1f/1/6)

If you're source database doesn't support LAG, then can you tell us what database/version it is so we can try to provide an alternative solution.

**Update:** Additional example using a CTE, for SQL Server versions prior to 2012:

```
WITH ntestCTE
AS (SELECT
  rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ntest.partnumber),
  ntest.partnumber,
  ntest.somevalue
FROM ntest)
SELECT
  ntestCTE.partnumber,
  ntestCTE.somevalue,
  CASE
    WHEN ntestCTE.partnumber <> prev.partnumber THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS PartNumberChangeOver
FROM ntestCTE
LEFT JOIN ntestCTE prev
  ON prev.rownum = ntestCTE.rownum - 1
```

[See it on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17e16f/1)

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Version 6.1.7601 is what we're using.

Comment: Then your best bet is to use a CTE to join the table back to itself, here's another example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17e16f/1