# distinct binary number in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have ignition status `1` and `0` every 10 minutes of interval time.
How to get distinct value like I won't repeating 1 and 0 number
When it's `1` with date time then next 0 will show and then next 1 will show

```
    ignition status   date time
    1                 2017-06-04  00:00:13.000
    0                 2017-06-04  02:36:29.000
    1                 2017-06-04  07:43:52.000
    0                 2017-06-04  23:56:18.000
```

```
query 
select top 100 ignitionstatus,datetime from rawdata
actual output 
ignitionstatus  stringdatetime
1              2017-05-26 17:17:50.000
1              2017-05-26 17:18:10.000
0              2017-05-26 17:18:30.000
1              2017-05-26 17:18:50.000
0              2017-05-26 17:19:30.000
1              2017-05-26 17:19:10.000
1              2017-05-26 17:20:10.000
we required
1              2017-05-26 17:17:50.000
0              2017-05-26 17:18:30.000
1              2017-05-26 17:18:50.000
1              2017-05-26 17:19:10.000
```

Comment: So is what you're showing us the *sample data* or the *expected results*? The question would be markedly improved by having *both*.

Comment: Remove time part from datetime. example:   case(datetime_Col As DATE)

Comment: Apparently you want to [flag records where `ignition status` changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32172037/11683) and only show them.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? (Taking table and column names from the query provided in the comments: `select ignitionstatus,stringdatetime from processedrawdata`) This uses a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER` to add a contiguous integer sequence to the rows:

```
WITH numbered_ignition_states AS 
(
    SELECT   row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY stringdatetime ),
             ignitionstatus,
             stringdatetime
    FROM     processedrawdata 
    ORDER BY stringdatetime
)
SELECT i1.ignitionstatus, i1.stringdatetime
FROM numbered_ignition_states i1, numbered_ignition_states i2
WHERE i1.row_num = 1 OR i1.row_num = i2.row_num + 1 AND i1.ignitionstatus != i2.ignitionstatus;
```

<s>Original suggestion, before more information was provided, assuming the table is called `ignition_states` and it has a contiguous integer primary key column `id`.</s>

```
SELECT i1.ignition_status, i1.date_time
FROM ignition_states i1, ignition_states i2
WHERE i1.id = 1 OR i1.id = i2.id + 1 AND i1.ignition_status != i2.ignition_status;
```

Comment: select ignitionstatus,stringdatetime from processedrawdata                                   ignitionstatus stringdatetime
1 2017-05-26 17:17:50.000
1 2017-05-26 17:18:10.000
1 2017-05-26 17:18:30.000
1 2017-05-26 17:18:50.000
1 2017-05-26 17:19:30.000
1 2017-05-26 17:19:10.000
1 2017-05-26 17:19:51.000
1 2017-05-26 17:20:10.000

Comment: @wasim - please don't post sample data as comments. Please *edit* your question (and format it as GSerg did with your expected output) so that it's *readable*.